# 0 and 1 - Switch Coverage in State Transition Testing?

Tags: testing, testcase, black-box-testing

This question is not programming related but related to one of test case design the technique. State Transition Diagram technique provides Test coverage by identifying test conditions via N-1 switch transitions.
I am confused about how to calculate the 0-switch and 1-switch coverage.

Adding screenshot of an example. Can anyone please explain how this can be solved?
Thank you in Advance.

[image: Question in screenshot]
[image: Diagram for this Question]

Answer (score 0):

The number of 0-switch from a state equals to the number of the transitions of length 1 starting from that state. In this case you have:

- ACT-ACT;
- ACT-ACC;
- ACT-DIS;
- ACT-CLO.

So, from Activated there are 4 transitions of length 1.

1-switch coverage from a state equals to all the transitions of length 2 starting from that state. You can build up from what you found in the 0-switch case, knowing which states you can reach from Activated in 1 transition. Just compute all the 0-switch transitions from each of these 4 states:

- ACT: (as computed earlier) ACT-ACT; ACT-ACC; ACT-DIS; ACT-CLO -> 4;
- ACC: ACC-ACT; ACC-CLO -> 2;
- DIS: DIS-ACT; DIS-CLO -> 2;
- CLO: CLO-DIS; CLO-ACT; CLO-REM; CLO-ACC -> 4.

In total, there are 12 1-STs.

But this is without considering the constraints in the second part of the exercise description.

"If a claim in state Accepted has been Closed it can only
be restored to the same state Accepted." -> it does not matter for the exercise, since we start from the state Activated.

"If a claim in state Activated has been Closed it can only be
restored to state Activated." -> this constraint rules out ACT-CLO-ACC.

So, in the end, you have 11 valid 1-STs.

Comment: Thank you Marco. Your solution helped me to under stand and solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 0-Switch transitions (states that you can reach with 1 leap from the Activated status):

- Activated
- Accepted
- Disputed
- Closed

There are 12 1-Switch transitions (states that you can reach with 2 leaps from the Activated status), however only 10 of them are valid:

- Activated - Activated
- Activated - Accepted
- Activated - Disputed
- Activated - Closed
- Accepted - Activated
- Accepted - Closed
- Disputed - Activated
- Disputed - Closed
- Closed - Activated
- Closed - Removed

The final restriction indicates that only Closed - Activated can be done, so Closed - Disputed, and Closed - Accepted do not count.

Answer (score 0):

> > Addendum for Marco answer<<

Total solution for 1-switch is 9.

You rule out 
ACT-CLO-ACC (as Marco said due to second restriction)

but You also rule out
ACT-CLO-REM (This one nobody excluded)
ACT-CLO-DIS (as Afner noted)